# Draw stroke inside/outside of path for arbitrary shapes and nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is a followup question of *[Is there a way to draw TikZ lines on the “inside” or “outside” of a path?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29991/4918)*

Since the other question is quite old I want to ask, if TikZ in the meantime is able to draw a stroke inside, on or outside of a path, like in this picture?

[image: stroke demo]

This was generated with the following code using `\pgflinewidth` to change the actual path. But this solution doesn’t work for arbitrary shapes and not for nodes, furthermore it is broken when scaling the picture.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   every node/.style = {below=5mm, text=black, font=\small},
%   scale = 1.5,
]
   % path
   \draw [red] (0,0) rectangle +(2,2)
      +(1,0) node {actual path};
   % stroke on path
   \draw [line width = 4mm] (3,0) rectangle +(2,2);
   \draw [red] (3,0) rectangle +(2,2)
      +(1,0) node {stroke on path};
   % stroke inside path
   \draw [line width = 4mm]
      ($(6,0)+(\pgflinewidth/2,\pgflinewidth/2)$) rectangle
      +($(2,2)-(\pgflinewidth,\pgflinewidth)$);
   \draw [red] (6,0) rectangle +(2,2)
      +(1,0) node {stroke inside path};
   % stroke outsie path
   \draw [line width = 4mm]
      ($(9,0)-(\pgflinewidth/2,\pgflinewidth/2)$) rectangle
      +($(2,2)+(\pgflinewidth,\pgflinewidth)$);
   \draw [red] (9,0) rectangle +(2,2)
      +(1,0) node {stroke outside path};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Actually I need it for drawing a row of nodes where some of them are filled and some are drawn, but the total hight should be equal and they should’t overlap. This is how it should *not* look like:

[image: node demo]

Instead the stroke of “State B” and “State C” should lie inside of the path. (The `postaction` is only for demonstration.)

Code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   every node/.style = {
      inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, postaction = {draw, red, thin},
      minimum height = 8mm, anchor = south west, font=\small
   },
   a/.style = {fill = gray},
   b/.style = {draw, line width = 2mm},
   c/.style = {draw, line width = 2mm, shape = signal },
]
   \node at (0,0) [minimum width = 20mm, a] {State A};
   \node at (2,0) [minimum width = 20mm, b] {State B};
   \node at (4,0) [minimum width = 30mm, a] {State A};
   \node at (7,0) [minimum width = 30mm, c] {State C};
   \draw [->] (0,-0.5) -- +(10.5,0);
   \foreach \x in {0,0.5,...,10}
      \draw (\x,-0.6) -- (\x,-0.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Enlarging State A is much simpler

Comment: @percusse: Yes maybe for rectangle shapes but in any cases the problem will be that the overlap is still there. If I move the left/right side of State A it will start/end at the wrong position of the x axis.

Comment: If you are OK with PGF syntax you can do it with http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53184/tikz-clip-shapes-with-another-built-in-shape

Comment: You really should include all the details in the first revision, because your question now might require a completely different solution, making existing answers incomplete —or wrong— in the process. Not a huge problem, but sometimes solutions can require a lot of work, so... :P

Comment: @Alenanno: Sorry. I wanted to keep the example code simple and clean but I also said in the first revision that it us about arbitrary shapes ;-)

Comment: @percusse: Thats a good tip. But it’ll only work if I know the shape of the node, cause in that solution I’d have to add the PGF code in the background and the user might change the shape. Is there a way to get the shape of the last node?

Comment: (I posted a [feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/98/) about this on source forge.)

Comment: No you don't need to know the shape. The shape will automatically clip its own picture. Think of it as `\node[clip,postaction={draw,ultra thick}] {...};`

Answer (score 5):

It is somewhat easy to come up with a decoration which draws the outside of a path.  In principle, one could reverse the path to get the curve drawn inside but that has some unforeseen consequences.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}    
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{stroke outside path}{initial}{%
  \state{initial}[width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/100,next state=iterate]
  {
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{.5\pgflinewidth}}
  }%
  \state{iterate}[width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/100]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.5\pgflinewidth}{.5\pgflinewidth}}
  }%
  \state{final}{%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgflinewidth}{.5\pgflinewidth}}{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}}
  }%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   every node/.style = {below=5mm, text=black, font=\small},
%   scale = 1.5,
]
   % path
   \draw [red] (0,0) rectangle +(2,2)
      +(1,0) node {actual path};
   % stroke on path
   \draw [line width = 4mm] (3,0) rectangle +(2,2);
   \draw [red] (3,0) rectangle +(2,2)
      +(1,0) node {stroke on path};
   % stroke inside path
   \draw [decoration={reverse path, stroke outside path}, decorate, line width = 4mm] (6,0) rectangle +(2,2);
   \draw [red] (6,0) rectangle +(2,2)
      +(1,0) node {stroke inside path};
   % stroke outsie path
   \draw [decoration=stroke outside path, decorate, line width = 4mm] (9,0) rectangle +(2,2);
   \draw [red] (9,0) rectangle +(2,2)
      +(1,0) node {stroke outside path};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [decoration=stroke outside path, decorate, line width = 4mm] (0,0) .. controls (1,-1) and (2,2) .. (3,0);
  \draw [red] (0,0) .. controls (1,-1) and (2,2) .. (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For this solution you need to load the `calc` library. Then we will basically draw a line for the `b` style, appended after the node has been set. Without `calc`, the line would appear like in your example, but using it, we can add or remove the `\pgflinewidth`.

I haven't tested it,  but it should be scalable.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style = {
       inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, postaction = {draw, red, thin},
       minimum height = 8mm, anchor = south west, font=\small
    },
    a/.style = {fill = gray},
    b/.style = {append after command={\pgfextra{
        \draw[line width=1mm] ($(\tikzlastnode.south west)+(.5\pgflinewidth,.5\pgflinewidth)$) rectangle ($(\tikzlastnode.north east)+(-.5\pgflinewidth,-.5\pgflinewidth)$);
    }}},
]
   \node at (0,0) [minimum width = 20mm, a] {State A};
   \node at (2,0) [minimum width = 20mm, b] {State B};
   \node at (4,0) [minimum width = 30mm, a] {State A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won’t work for arbitrary (node) shapes …

Comment: @Tobi How many arbitrary shapes will you use? And which ones?

Comment: Actually I can’t tell. This is part of a package and the user can define the shapes. The default will use rectangles and triangles in the form of volume bars (no default shapes, I’ll define them for this purpose)