# filling an intersection between shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill, clip

I need assistance in finding out how to fill the intersection between the shapes RO1, RO2, RO4, RO5 in the following. Assistance appreciated.

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw, ellipse, thick, rotate=90, green!50!black, minimum width=9cm, minimum height=4.4cm, align=center] at (0,0.7)(RO1){};
\node [draw, ellipse, thick, rotate=24, green!50!black, minimum width=9cm, minimum height=4.4cm, align=center] at (0.2,-0.5)(RO2){};
\node [draw, ellipse, thick, rotate=162, green!50!black, minimum width=8cm, minimum height=4.4cm, align=center] at (-0.7,0.5)(RO5){};
\node [draw, ellipse, thick, rotate=235, green!50!black, minimum width=9cm, minimum height=4.4cm, align=center] at (-1.33,-0.7)(RO4){};
\node [draw, ellipse, thick, rotate=130, green!50!black, minimum width=9cm, minimum height=4.4cm, align=center] at (-0.1,-1.5)(RO3){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have seen this as [example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/intersecting-rings/) and the [TikZ/pgf guide](https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf) how to fill an intersection?

Comment: Can you add a scan of a handmade coloring so that we can agree on the area to color?

Comment: I have added image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have time to explain how I did it because I have to go to lunch (sorry).

Be aware that instead of trying to find the intersection of nodes that is very difficult and complicated, I rewrote the ellipses as a path.

I will explain later if you wish.

[image: intersection]

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\plan{(-5,-5.5)rectangle(5,6)}
\def\ellipseone{(0,0.7) circle [x radius=4.5cm, y radius=22mm, rotate=90]}
\def\ellipsetwo{(0.2,-0.5) circle [x radius=4.5cm, y radius=22mm, rotate=24]}
\def\ellipsethree{(-0.1,-1.5)circle [x radius=4.5cm, y radius=22mm, rotate=130]}
\def\ellipsefour{(-1.33,-0.7) circle [x radius=4.5cm, y radius=22mm, rotate=235]}
\def\ellipsefive{(-0.7,0.5) circle [x radius=4cm, y radius=22mm, rotate=162]}

%\node [draw, ellipse, thick, rotate=90, green!50!black, minimum width=9cm, minimum height=4.4cm, align=center,name path global=RO1] at (0,0.7)(RO1){};


%%\clip\plan;
\draw[green!50!black]\ellipseone;
\draw[green!50!black]\ellipsetwo;
\draw[green!50!black]\ellipsethree;
\draw[green!50!black]\ellipsefour;
\draw[green!50!black]\ellipsefive;

\clip\ellipsefour;
\clip\ellipsetwo;
\clip\ellipsefive;
\clip\ellipseone;
\fill[orange!80,even odd rule]\plan\ellipsethree;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If this solution has solved your problem, it is customary to accept it. Read: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @AndréC Perfect! Very beautiful.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you, I first looked for how to make the intersection of shape and I found the answer of percusse: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53195/138900  as it is complicated I went to the simplest by adapting this solution: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/set-operations-illustrated-with-venn-diagrams/