# How to clip a background including nodes according to an arbitrary shape?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following `WE`

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes, positioning, fit, backgrounds}

\tikzstyle{backA}=[rectangle,
fill=blue!30,
inner sep=0.2cm,
rounded corners=0mm]

\tikzstyle{backB}=[rectangle,
fill=purple!15,
inner sep=0.2cm,
rounded corners=0mm]

\tikzstyle{backC}=[rectangle,
fill=yellow!40,
inner sep=0.2cm,
rounded corners=0mm]

\tikzset{%
  >={Latex[width=2mm,length=2mm]},
            base/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black,
                           minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm,
                           text centered,inner sep=0.3cm},
  operation/.style = {base, fill=SkyBlue},
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.8cm,
    every node/.style={fill=white}, align=center]
    \node (controller) [operation] {Microcontroller};
    \node (regulator) [operation, below = of controller] {Regulator};
    \node (transceiver) [operation, right = of controller, align = center] {CAN \\ Transceiver};
    \node (sensor) [operation, above = of controller] {Sensor};
    \node (flash) [operation, below = of transceiver, yshift=4mm] {Flash \\ Memeory};
    \node (driver1) [operation, right = of sensor] {Driver 1};
    \node (driver2) [operation, left = of sensor] {Driver 2};
    \node (power) [operation, left = of regulator, align=center] {Input \\ Power};
    \node (motor1) [operation, above = of sensor, align=center, xshift=1cm] {Motor 1};
    \node (motor2) [operation, above = of sensor, align=center, xshift=-1cm] {Motor 2};
    \node[circle,draw,fill=SkyBlue] (computer) [right = of driver1] {Computer};
    \coordinate[left = of power] (d1) {};
    \coordinate[above = of d1, yshift=5.5cm] (d2) {};

    \draw[->]             (controller) -- (transceiver);
    \draw[<->]             (controller) -- (sensor);
    \draw[->]             (driver1) -- (motor1);
    \draw[->]             (driver2) -- (motor2);
    \draw[<->]             (sensor) -- (motor2);
    \draw[<->]             (sensor) -- (motor1);
    \draw[->]             (controller) -- (driver1);
    \draw[->]             (controller) -- (driver2);
    \draw[->]             (controller) -- (flash);
    \draw[->]             (regulator) -- (controller);
    \draw[->]             (power) -- (regulator);
    \draw[<->]             (transceiver) -- (computer);
    \draw[->]             (power) -- (d1) |- (motor2);
    \draw[->]             (power) -- (d1) --  (d2) -| (motor1);

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node [backC,
    fit=(driver1) (driver2) (sensor) (motor1) (motor2),
    label=above:{}] {};

    \node [backA,
    fit=(computer) (transceiver),
    label=above:{}] {};

    \node [backB,
    fit=(regulator) (power),
    label=above:{}] {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Since the `driver1` node should have been exclusively covered by the yellow background, I need to subtract the specific part of the violet background which interferes with the yellow one. In particular, an acceptable boundary for the violet background may roughly be like this:

[image]

How can I achieve something like that?

Comment: Might be useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53184/tikz-clip-shapes-with-another-built-in-shape

Comment: I don't think you need to crop the blue part. You only have to draw the yellow part _after_ the blue part -- in that case, the yellow part will overfill the blue part.

Comment: @Roboticist If I understand your comment, you only need to put a white frame of the yellow part. This can be done with `draw=white`.

Comment: @JouleV: The yellow background is indeed drawn "after" the blue background in the `WE`. Additionally, I'd like to know a potential approach to achieving margins with arbitrary shapes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not overdraw areas with white, imagine you have some background you want to keep. And `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes, positioning, fit, backgrounds}

% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12033/121799
\tikzset{reverseclip/.style={insert path={(current bounding box.south west)rectangle 
  (current bounding box.north east)} }}

\tikzset{backA/.style={rectangle,
fill=blue!30,
inner sep=0.2cm,
rounded corners=0mm},
backB/.style={rectangle,
fill=purple!15,
inner sep=0.2cm,
rounded corners=0mm},
backC/.style={rectangle,
fill=yellow!40,
inner sep=0.2cm,
rounded corners=0mm}}

\tikzset{%
  >={Latex[width=2mm,length=2mm]},
            base/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black,
                           minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm,
                           text centered,inner sep=0.3cm},
  operation/.style = {base, fill=SkyBlue},
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.8cm,
    every node/.style={fill=white}, align=center]
    \node (controller) [operation] {Microcontroller};
    \node (regulator) [operation, below = of controller] {Regulator};
    \node (transceiver) [operation, right = of controller, align = center] {CAN \\ Transceiver};
    \node (sensor) [operation, above = of controller] {Sensor};
    \node (flash) [operation, below = of transceiver, yshift=4mm] {Flash \\ Memeory};
    \node (driver1) [operation, right = of sensor] {Driver 1};
    \node (driver2) [operation, left = of sensor] {Driver 2};
    \node (power) [operation, left = of regulator, align=center] {Input \\ Power};
    \node (motor1) [operation, above = of sensor, align=center, xshift=1cm] {Motor 1};
    \node (motor2) [operation, above = of sensor, align=center, xshift=-1cm] {Motor 2};
    \node[circle,draw,fill=SkyBlue] (computer) [right = of driver1] {Computer};
    \coordinate[left = of power] (d1) {};
    \coordinate[above = of d1, yshift=5.5cm] (d2) {};

    \draw[->]             (controller) -- (transceiver);
    \draw[<->]             (controller) -- (sensor);
    \draw[->]             (driver1) -- (motor1);
    \draw[->]             (driver2) -- (motor2);
    \draw[<->]             (sensor) -- (motor2);
    \draw[<->]             (sensor) -- (motor1);
    \draw[->]             (controller) -- (driver1);
    \draw[->]             (controller) -- (driver2);
    \draw[->]             (controller) -- (flash);
    \draw[->]             (regulator) -- (controller);
    \draw[->]             (power) -- (regulator);
    \draw[<->]             (transceiver) -- (computer);
    \draw[->]             (power) -- (d1) |- (motor2);
    \draw[->]             (power) -- (d1) --  (d2) -| (motor1);

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node [backC,
    fit=(driver1) (driver2) (sensor) (motor1) (motor2),
    label=above:{}] (F1){};

    \node [backB,
    fit=(regulator) (power),
    label=above:{}] {};
    \clip ([xshift=-5pt,yshift=-5pt]F1.south west) -|
    ([xshift=5pt,yshift=5pt]F1.north east) -| cycle  [reverseclip];
    \node [backA,
    fit=(computer) (transceiver),
    label=above:{}] {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just saw your retirement announcement. Thanks for everything, not only for your TikZ and LaTeX knowledge but also for your sense of humor and your passion to share what you know.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes, positioning, fit, backgrounds}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{middle}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,middle,foreground}
\tikzstyle{backA}=[rectangle,
fill=blue!30,
inner sep=0.2cm,
rounded corners=0mm]

\tikzstyle{backB}=[rectangle,
fill=purple!15,
inner sep=0.2cm,
rounded corners=0mm]

\tikzstyle{backC}=[rectangle,
fill=yellow!40,
%inner sep=0.2cm,
rounded corners=0mm]

\tikzset{%
  >={Latex[width=2mm,length=2mm]},
            base/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black,
                           minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm,
                           text centered,inner sep=0.3cm},
  operation/.style = {base, fill=SkyBlue},
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.8cm,
    every node/.style={fill=white}, align=center]
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
    \node (controller) [operation] {Microcontroller};
    \node (regulator) [operation, below = of controller] {Regulator};
    \node (transceiver) [operation, right = of controller, align = center] {CAN \\ Transceiver};
    \node (sensor) [operation, above = of controller] {Sensor};
    \node (flash) [operation, below = of transceiver, yshift=4mm] {Flash \\ Memeory};
    \node (driver1) [operation, right = of sensor] {Driver 1};
    \node (driver2) [operation, left = of sensor] {Driver 2};
    \node (power) [operation, left = of regulator, align=center] {Input \\ Power};
    \node (motor1) [operation, above = of sensor, align=center, xshift=1cm] {Motor 1};
    \node (motor2) [operation, above = of sensor, align=center, xshift=-1cm] {Motor 2};
    \node[circle,draw,fill=SkyBlue] (computer) [right = of driver1] {Computer};
    \coordinate[left = of power] (d1) {};
    \coordinate[above = of d1, yshift=5.5cm] (d2) {};

    \draw[->]             (controller) -- (transceiver);
    \draw[<->]             (controller) -- (sensor);
    \draw[->]             (driver1) -- (motor1);
    \draw[->]             (driver2) -- (motor2);
    \draw[<->]             (sensor) -- (motor2);
    \draw[<->]             (sensor) -- (motor1);
    \draw[->]             (controller) -- (driver1);
    \draw[->]             (controller) -- (driver2);
    \draw[->]             (controller) -- (flash);
    \draw[->]             (regulator) -- (controller);
    \draw[->]             (power) -- (regulator);
    \draw[<->]             (transceiver) -- (computer);
    \draw[->]             (power) -- (d1) |- (motor2);
    \draw[->]             (power) -- (d1) --  (d2) -| (motor1);
\end{pgfonlayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{middle}
    \node [backC,
    fit=(driver1) (driver2) (sensor) (motor1) (motor2),
    label=above:{}] {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{main}
    \node [fill=white,inner sep=3mm,
    fit=(driver1) (driver2) (sensor) (motor1) (motor2),
    label=above:{}] {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node [backA,
    fit=(computer) (transceiver),
    label=above:{}] {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
    \node [backB,
    fit=(regulator) (power),
    label=above:{}] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can one insert a little of white margin between the boundaries of the two backgrounds? I mean, the backgrounds are tangent to each other right now.

Comment: @Roboticist I have updated my answer by adding another layer named `middle`

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary shapes (not nodes), one cannot use fitting.
[image: demo]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes, positioning, calc, backgrounds}

\tikzset{%
  >={Latex[width=2mm,length=2mm]},
            base/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black,
                           minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm,
                           text centered,inner sep=0.3cm},
  operation/.style = {base, fill=SkyBlue},
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.8cm,
    every node/.style={fill=white}, align=center]
    \node (controller) [operation] {Microcontroller};
    \node (regulator) [operation, below = of controller] {Regulator};
    \node (transceiver) [operation, right = of controller, align = center] {CAN \\ Transceiver};
    \node (sensor) [operation, above = of controller] {Sensor};
    \node (flash) [operation, below = of transceiver, yshift=4mm] {Flash \\ Memeory};
    \node (driver1) [operation, right = of sensor] {Driver 1};
    \node (driver2) [operation, left = of sensor] {Driver 2};
    \node (power) [operation, left = of regulator, align=center] {Input \\ Power};
    \node (motor1) [operation, above = of sensor, align=center, xshift=1cm] {Motor 1};
    \node (motor2) [operation, above = of sensor, align=center, xshift=-1cm] {Motor 2};
    \node[circle,draw,fill=SkyBlue] (computer) [right = of driver1] {Computer};
    \coordinate[left = of power] (d1) {};
    \coordinate[above = of d1, yshift=5.5cm] (d2) {};

    \draw[->]             (controller) -- (transceiver);
    \draw[<->]             (controller) -- (sensor);
    \draw[->]             (driver1) -- (motor1);
    \draw[->]             (driver2) -- (motor2);
    \draw[<->]             (sensor) -- (motor2);
    \draw[<->]             (sensor) -- (motor1);
    \draw[->]             (controller) -- (driver1);
    \draw[->]             (controller) -- (driver2);
    \draw[->]             (controller) -- (flash);
    \draw[->]             (regulator) -- (controller);
    \draw[->]             (power) -- (regulator);
    \draw[<->]             (transceiver) -- (computer);
    \draw[->]             (power) -- (d1) |- (motor2);
    \draw[->]             (power) -- (d1) --  (d2) -| (motor1);

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \path (driver1.east |- computer.north) ++ (0.2,0.2) coordinate(int1);
    \path (driver2.south -| transceiver.west) ++ (-0.2,-0.2) coordinate(int2);

    \fill[yellow!40] ($(driver2.south west)+(-0.2,-0.2)$) |- ($(motor2.north)+(0,0.2)$) -| (int1) -- (int2) -- cycle;
    \fill[blue!30] ($(transceiver.south west)+(-0.2,-0.2)$) -- (int2) -- (int1) -- 
      ($(computer.north)+(0,0.2)$) -| ($(computer.east)+(0.2,0)$) |- cycle;
    \fill[purple!15] ($(power.south west)+(-0.2,-0.2)$) |- ($(power.north)+(0,0.2)$) -| ($(regulator.east)+(0.2,0.2)$) |- cycle;
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```